# MapActivity class not resolved to type even when project build target is Google

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm trying to integrate Google maps into an app I am working on. I followed the set up guide and have already made sure the build target for project is one of the Google API targets. However, eclipse is still telling me that MapActivity is not a class.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an issue when compiling or when running the app?

If it's at compile time, did you import the class

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
```

You'd also need to override the isRouteDisplayed() method

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

As mentioned by Robert Estivill, more information is needed!

Comment: I added that in the .java file

Comment: This fixed did not realize I had to import the MapActivity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the Google Maps library declaration on your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application ... 
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
     ....
 </application>
```

Comment: I added that in the Manifest it still says its not a class. That's why this is confusing. I followed all the steps on Google's set up doc.

Comment: Are you testing against a device that has the maps library installed? Such as an AVD with Google Api's or a real phone?

Comment: I'm using an AVD with Google Api's

Comment: Can you add the AndroidManifest.xml and the error logcat please?